# error facebook sdk 4.1.2 LoginButton to eclipse

Tags: android

```
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fbtest/com.example.fbtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:169)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at com.example.fbtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    ... 11 more
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.fbtest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.fbtest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /data/datalib]]
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-18 19:05:06.591: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Can we see your code and some explanation too?

Comment: i just add facebook libary and add this

Comment: i just add libary to project and facebook button it's error this still not write code in my MainAcitivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you import sdk library into eclipse,have you mark project As Library, and import that to your project?

Comment: yes im do, it's error when i add 
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="  connect_with_facebook" />